# if statement skipped , uppercase letters not displaying

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-animate

I'm making a mini game for my multimedia class using Adobe Animate with ActionScript 3.

The first question requires the user to fill in the blanks to print "hi" like in python.

the question looks like this

> > > _____("hi")

then you would fill in the blanks and click on a check answer button.

Then to check if the answer is correct I use an if-else statement like so :

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

checkBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkClick);

function checkClick(event:MouseEvent): void
{ 
    if(input1.text == "print")
    {
        ans1.text = "Correct!";
    }
    else 
    {
        ans1.text = "Wrong answer!";

    }

    }
```

However, even if the input is correct, it will skip the if part of the code and run straight into else.
It also won't display uppercase letters?

It'll display "rong answer!" ignoring the uppercase "W".

Any ideas?

Comment: **Uppercase**: you need to check the embedded font and ensure if uppercase range A-Z is included. Seems like it is missing. **Ignored 'if'**: the fact you enter "*print*" does not mean **input1.text** is exactly "*print*". It could contain leading or tailing spaces or line breaks, i.e. "*print *" or "*print\n*, or maybe HTML-formatting like "*<p>print</p>*". In order to solve that you need to learn what's in that input **TextField** exactly, all the characters one by one, then act appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

@Organis is right; The font needs to be embedded.

> Flash Professional CS5 (and later) automatically embeds any characters used by text fields on the Stage. However, if you are using Dynamic or Input text fields, the project may also need to include characters for the font that aren't specifically contained in instances on the Stage during authoring. If you do not embed the necessary characters and text elements are programmatically displayed or entered by the user, the characters may be missing and the application may appear broken.

[Common Mistakes Working with Fonts and Text Objects in Flash](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/avoiding-mistakes-text.html)

For help embedding fonts, refer to the Adobe documentation on it.

[Embedding Fonts with ActionScript](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts.html)

[Embedding Fonts in Adobe Animate (Flash)](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/how-to/embed-fonts.html)